# How to negate words in regex with word boundaries for reserved words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am trying to do a reserved words validation with rails

```
validates :reserved_words, format: { with: /\A^(?!.*\badmin\b|\bfoo\b|\bbar\b).*$\z/i, message: 'reserved words' }
```

Above is what I have tried.. but I think it's very cumbersome to use `\bword\b` everytime for the word boundary.. is there more effective ways to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
\A(?!.*\b(?:admin|foo|bar)\b).*\z
```

You can shorten it this way.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/32